# Installing pip on Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

Although I installed Python 3.8.5 from python.org, which should automatically install pip, I can't locate pip in the Python38 folder. Normally, it is located in the Scripts folder but there is no Scripts folder. Also, the folder site-packages does not include any packages, only a 'READ-ME' file. I typed 'pip help' in the command window to check whether pip is installed but for almost any command I get the message 'Invalid syntax'.

```
>>> pip help
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip help
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To install pip, I typed 'python get-pip.py' and 'pip install pip' but this leads to the same error.

```
>>> python get-pip.py  
 File "<stdin>", line 1
    python get-pip.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> pip install pip
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pip
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> sudo apt-get install pip3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo apt-get install pip3
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I repaired the installation to ensure all features were correctly installed but this didn't help either although there were no errors in either the installation or repair and IDLE works fine except that packages that should normally have been installed like matplotlib and numpy have not been installed.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding these issues?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: I've seen several issues on http://bugs.python.org in which pip and setuptools silently fail to install, and there's either no scripts directory, or it's empty.  It's a rare problem, but you're not alone. Thus far there hasn't been enough information from setup logs to resolve the issue with the installer. From a command prompt (not Python's shell) try running `python -m ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip`. If you installed Python for all users, you'll have to run the latter from an administrator command prompt.

Comment: That the OP doesn't understanding the difference between the system shell and the Python shell (REPL) is entirely beside the point here. pip did not install, which is a known bug with the installer, but at this point the reason for the failure is a mystery.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add pip path to environmental variables.

Just follow these steps mentioned in the below `URL`

> https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Thank uou

Answer (score -1):

One problem might be that python is not set as Environment variable path, if that is the problem go to python installer select "modify" then check all the statement that appear on the first page and on the second page make sure that "add python to environment variable" is checked.